# Exception when calling delegate in Xamarin Objective C binding

Tags: ios, objective-c, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am getting an exception thrown whenever the `Canceled` method of my delegate gets called from my Objective-C library.

```
ObjCRuntime.RuntimeException: Could not find the method 'Canceled' in the type 'MCImagePicker+_MCImagePickerDelegate'.   at ObjCRuntime.Runtime.FindMethod (IntPtr typeptr, IntPtr methodptr, Int32 paramCount, System.IntPtr* paramptr)
```

It says the method is not found, however the method is defined in the binding. Here is the binding that I use:

```
// @protocol MCImagePickerDelegate <NSObject>
[Protocol, Model]
[BaseType(typeof(NSObject))]
interface MCImagePickerDelegate
{
    // @optional -(void)imagePicker:(MCImagePicker *)imagePicker pickedImage:(UIImage *)image;
    [Export("imagePicker:pickedImage:"), EventArgs("ImagePicked")]
    void PickedImage(MCImagePicker imagePicker, UIImage image);

    // @optional -(void)imagePickerDidCancel:(MCImagePicker *)imagePicker;
    [Export("imagePickerDidCancel:")]
    void Canceled(MCImagePicker imagePicker);
}

// @interface MCImagePicker : NSObject
[BaseType(typeof(NSObject),
    Delegates = new string[] { "WeakDelegate" },
    Events = new Type[] { typeof(MCImagePickerDelegate) })]
interface MCImagePicker
{

    [Wrap("WeakDelegate")]
    MCImagePickerDelegate Delegate { get; set; }

    // @property (nonatomic) id<MCImagePickerDelegate> delegate;
    [NullAllowed, Export("delegate", ArgumentSemantic.Assign)]
    NSObject WeakDelegate { get; set; }

    // -(void)showFromController:(UIViewController *)controller completion:(void(^)(void))completion;
    [Export("showFromController:completion:")]
    [Async]
    void ShowFromController(UIViewController controller, Action completion);


    // -(void)dismiss:(void(^)(void))completion;
    [Export("dismiss:")]
    [Async]
    void Dismiss(Action completion);
}
```

Note: This happens only for the Canceled method. The ImagePicked method gets called correctly without any exceptions.

If I look in the generated code the Canceled method is generated. Here is an excerpt of the generated code:

```
[Protocol]
[Register("MCImagePickerDelegate", false)]
[Model]
public unsafe partial class MCImagePickerDelegate : NSObject, IMCImagePickerDelegate {

    [Export ("imagePickerDidCancel:")]
    [CompilerGenerated]
    public virtual void Canceled (MCImagePicker imagePicker)
    {
        throw new You_Should_Not_Call_base_In_This_Method ();
    }
}


#pragma warning disable 672
[Register]
sealed class _MCImagePickerDelegate : MCImagePickerDelegate {
    public _MCImagePickerDelegate () { IsDirectBinding = false; }

    internal EventHandler canceled;
    [Preserve (Conditional = true)]
    public override void Canceled (MCImagePicker imagePicker)
    {
        EventHandler handler = canceled;
        if (handler != null){
            handler (imagePicker, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question, since I figured out a fix.

This seems to happen because I have `EventArgs` on the other method in delegate. If I update the binding so that the `Canceled` method has `EventArgs` as well:

```
    // @optional -(void)imagePickerDidCancel:(MCImagePicker *)imagePicker;
    [Export("imagePickerDidCancel:"), EventArgs("ImagePicked")]
    void Canceled(MCImagePicker imagePicker);
```

After ***rebuilding*** the solution this works. Note the rebuild step is necessary.

I am not exactly sure what changes and how this fixes the issue since the generated code is exactly the same (I diffed it). But it worked for me.

**Update:**

You just need to clean and rebuild the solution. That is all that is required. Ignore the thing about adding an `EventArgs` attribute. It seems to be that Xamarin has a bug in the build process.